# Using a path to an array item

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to reference an item within a multidimensional array by using a path or an array of path elements? EG.

```
$multi = array
(
    'array_1' => array
    (
        'array_2' => array
        (
            'option_1' => 'value_1',
            'option_2' => 'value_2',
        )
    )
);

$path = array('level_1', 'level_2', 'option_1');
$result = $multi[$path];
```

And have $result = 'value_1'?

The reason being, I have a recursive function for searching thru $multi and finding the key I need, and returning the $path. I know i can hard code in the path from my own code but i'm trying to make this reusable so that i can edit the $multi and the function will still work.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please show exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Won't `$result = $multi['array_1']['array_2']['option_1'];` do the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built into PHP to do this but you can write a function for it, using a moving reference:

```
/**
 * @param string $path path in the form 'item_1.item_2.[...].item_n'
 * @param array $array original array
 */
function &get_from_array($path, &$array)
{
    $current =& $array;
    foreach(explode('.', $path) as $key) {
        $current =& $current[$key];
    }
    return $current;
}
```

Example:

```
// get element:
$result = get_from_array('level_1.level_2.option_1', $multi);
echo $result; // --> value_1

$result = 'changed option';
echo $multi['level_1']['level_2']['option_1']; // --> changed_option
```

I wrote it to convert names from configuration files to arrays, if you want to pass the path itself as an array like in your example, just leave out the explode.