# PHP string to array keys

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that holds the property and key values to accessing a value on an object..

For Example, the string is "property_name[key1][key2][key3]", which relates to `$obj->property_name[key1][key2][key3]`

I've been trying to parse the string with a regular expression, but all of my attempts have ben in vain.

So far, my regular expression looks like this, but it won't get key2.
`^(\w+)\[([^\]]+)\](?:(\[([^\]]+)\])+)`

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this that I should try?

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. Where do you get these strings from? Maybe you can save them as JSON instead?

Comment: They're the names of fields in a form that have been changed.  I'm trying to update a few fields in multiple records when a user changes a value from my form. I'm using javascript to save the field names to a hidden element to get these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression could look like this:

```
^(\w+)(?:\[(\w+)\])+
```

Then your matches will contain the property name and the array keys. If the number of keys varies, use this to get the actual value: [Using a path to an array item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799012/using-a-path-to-an-array-item/14799059#14799059)

Comment: I ended up using a combination of the link here and this regular expression `@^(\w+)(\[([^]].*)\])@`

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX instead and send a useful array with objects inside to the server that you can parse with PHP.

```
var changed_values = [
                      {
                       'part_of_form': 'XX',
                       'field': 2,
                       'subfield': 3
                      },
        .......
                     ]
```

Then in PHP you can loop over it:

```
foreach($_POST['changed_values'] as $changed_value) {
  ........
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do.